# Unable to access Json object properties / values - showing undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table where I am attempting to get values from a clicked row onto a modal box. My data is being returned to the view, but I have issues accessing the property values of my object.

This is my currency code
Script

```
$('.item-list tr td').click(function () {
    var clickedRow = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(5)').text();

    $.ajax({
        "url": "/ActivityType/Details",
        "type": "POST",
        "dataType": "JSON",
        "data": { aActivityID: clickedRow },
        "success": function (data) {
            //var thisData = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(data);

            console.log(data.activityName);                
            console.log(data["activityName"]);
            console.log(data['activityName']);

            document.getElementById("ActivityName").value = data[0].activityName;
            showAjaxModal();
        }
    });
});
```

Controller

```
public IActionResult Details(System.Guid aActivityID)
    {
        if (aActivityID != System.Guid.Empty)
        {
            t_activitytype aActivity = new t_activitytype();
            aActivity = db.t_activitytype.Where(a => a.Guid == aActivityID).First();

            return Json(new { data = aActivity });
        }
        return View();
    }
```

`console.log(data);` shows my object with its property values
[image]

trying to access the properties at this point returns 'undefined' for the following lines

`console.log(data.activityName);
 console.log(data["activityName"]);
 console.log(data['activityName']);`

[image]

Comment: It looks like the structure might be `data.data.activityName`.

Comment: Notice in your console log, the first (and only) property off of the element you logged is `data`

Comment: So instead of `return Json(new { data = aActivity });` just do `return Json(aActivity)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller includes a `data` property in the data itself. You can actually see that addition `data` in the console. So probably you would better remove that extra layer at the server side.

Instead of

```
return Json(new { data = aActivity });
```

just do

```
return Json(aActivity)
```

Comment: thanks trincot, that solved it. I will keep that in mind, that the controller includes a data property.